# A more elegant way of deleting the last value of multiple lists?

Tags: python, list, numpy

I have multiple lists namely, `X`, `Y`, `VX`, `VY`, `R`, `T`, `KE`, `PE`, `TE`, for which I need to delete their (i+1)th value off once their iterations break. The way I can do it currently is if I do:

```
del X[i+1:]
del Y[i+1:]
del VX[i+1:]
del VY[i+1:]
del R[i+1:]
del T[i+1:]
del KE[i+1:]
del PE[i+1:]
del TE[i+1:]
```

Which I think it looks rather ugly. Is there a way to minimize the use of lines in this case. Maybe a loop which does that but in just 1 or 2 lines?

Edit:
I didn't want to include the body of my code because I'm aware that a lot of my colleagues are doing the same problem and I don't want anyone to plagiarize. Anyway, here's what I did.

```
def F_1(X):
    return VX

def F_2(X):
    return VY

def F_3(X, Y):
    return -G*EM*X/((X**2 + Y**2)**(3/2))

def F_4(X, Y):
    return -G*EM*Y/((X**2 + Y**2)**(3/2))

def RKutta(F_1, F_2, F_3, F_4, XSTART, YSTART, VXSTART, VYSTART):
    N = 100000
    X, Y = np.zeros([N+1]), np.zeros([N+1])
    VX, VY = np.zeros([N+1]), np.zeros([N+1])
    R, T =  np.zeros([N+1]), np.zeros([N+1])
    KE, PE, TE = np.zeros([N+1]), np.zeros(N+1), np.zeros([N+1])

    X[0], Y[0] = XSTART, YSTART
    VX[0], VY[0] = VXSTART, VYSTART
    T[0] = 0
#    KE[0], PE[0], TE[0] = KE, PE, TE

    for i in range (1,N):

        K_1X = F_1(VX[i-1])
        K_1Y = F_2(VY[i-1])
        K_1VX = F_3(X[i-1], Y[i-1])
        K_1VY = F_4(X[i-1], Y[i-1])

        K_2X = F_1(VX[i-1] + (H*K_1VX/2))
        K_2Y = F_2(VY[i-1] + (H*K_1VY/2))
        K_2VX = F_3(X[i-1] + (H*K_1X/2), Y[i-1] + (H*K_1Y/2))
        K_2VY = F_4(X[i-1] + (H*K_1X/2), Y[i-1] + (H*K_1Y/2))

        K_3X = F_1(VX[i-1] + (H*K_2VX/2))
        K_3Y = F_2(VY[i-1] + (H*K_2VY/2))
        K_3VX = F_3(X[i-1] + (H*K_2X/2), Y[i-1] + (H*K_2Y/2))
        K_3VY = F_4(X[i-1] + (H*K_2X/2), Y[i-1] + (H*K_2Y/2))

        K_4X = F_1(VX[i-1] + H*K_3VX)
        K_4Y = F_2(VY[i-1] + H*K_3VY)
        K_4VX = F_3(X[i-1] + H*K_3X, Y[i-1] + H*K_3Y)
        K_4VY = F_4(X[i-1] + H*K_3X, Y[i-1] + H*K_3Y)

        X[i] = X[i-1] + (H/6)*(K_1X + 2*K_2X + 2*K_3X + K_4X)
        Y[i] = Y[i-1] + (H/6)*(K_2Y + 2*K_2Y + 2*K_3Y + K_4Y)
        VX[i] = VX[i-1] + (H/6)*(K_1VX + 2*K_2VX + 2*K_3VX + 2*K_4VX)
        VY[i] = VY[i-1] + (H/6)*(K_1VY + 2*K_2VY + 2*K_3VY + 2*K_4VY)
        R[i] = ((X[i])**2 + (Y[i])**2)**(0.5)
        T[i] = T[i-1] + H

        KE[i] = ((VX[i]**2 + VY[i]**2)/2)
        PE[i] = (-1*G*EM/R[i])
        TE[i] = KE[i] + PE[i]

        if R[i] < 6.371E6:  #if orbit radius is less than Earth radius
            break

        for sublist in [X, Y, VX, VY, R, T, KE, PE, TE]:
            del sublist[i+1:]

    return X, Y, VX, VY, R, T, KE, PE, TE

X = 3.84E8
Y = 0
X, Y, VX, VY, R, T, KE, PE = RKutta(F_1, F_2, F_3, F_4, X, Y, VX, VY)

plt.plot(X, Y, label = "")
plt.xlabel("X distance (m)")
plt.ylabel("Y distance (m)")
plt.title("X against Y")
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

I'm trying to implement 4th-order Runge-Kutta method to simulate a rocket orbiting the Earth. The goal is to finally print out the orbit of the rocket. I'm still figuring out my code so they're still not working yet. How would using class improve this?

Comment: Yes, store your lists in a list. Or a dict. Or something.

Comment: How can I do that?

Comment: why are your lists unrelated? your lists should be in a matrix or a list of lists somehow.

Comment: "the elegant way" will be storing your lists in list and create new list instead of deleting elements

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre the lists are the position, speed, energies of an rocket orbital motion

Comment: also seems to be [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Comment: if they are related how about creating a class `Rocket` with corresponding fields?

Comment: `[i+1:]` is not necessarily the last value in a list, which would be `[-1]`. What exactly to you mean?

Comment: @user3613025 it's better to create a class in that case with position, speed, energies, ... for each. Quit Fortran-programming style with only indices binding all related values.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre I tried creating class but in the end i don't understand how to use it. I did this

`def Constants():  
    def __init__(self, type, mass = None, xcoord = None, ycoord = None, xvel = None, yvel = None, h = None):  
        self.type = type  
        self.mass = mass  
        self.xcoord = xcoord
        self.ycoord = ycoord
        self.xvel = xvel
        self.yvel = yvel
        self.h = h `

then I don't know where to go from here lol. The concept of class baffles me even after I read up about them

Comment: @martineau Sorry what I meant to say was I had many lists iterating when when it hit a certain condition it "breaks" and then I delete the values in the lists after they break

Comment: user3613025: I see...now it make more sense. I would strongly suggest taking @Jean-FrançoisFabre's comment about Fortran-style programming seriously. He meant, I think, that instead of having a bunch of related items stored in separate lists/arrays grouped implicitly via a common index, like `i`, processing is often easier and cleaner if each group of them is put inside some other container, such as making them instance attribute of a custom `class`. That way an entire group could be operated upon all in one go. i.e. a single `del my_data[i]` would eliminate the entire `i`th group of them.

Comment: user3613025: P.S. That's also what @Aran-Fey meant, I believe.

Comment: @martineau if I show you my code in private would you be able to give me some pointers as to how I could change them into classes?

Comment: user3613025: I probably don't need to see your actual code if the answer to your question I just posted helps clarify things enough.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre please see my edits above. How can I use class in this scenario?

Comment: @user3613025 i edited my answer to reflect reflect the class approach. Add a comment if you need further clarification or if you understand :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Keep references of your list in another data structure and then loop through that to delete everything at once:

```
for sublist in [X, Y, VX, VY, R, T, KE, PE, TE]:
    del sublist[i+1:]
```

Edit:
You wanted to use classes instead of lists.

Right now you have nine lists, and the ith element in each list corresponds to an attribute about the ith rocket. So you can create a rocket class:

```
class Rocket:
    def __init__(self, X, Y, VX, VY, R, T, KE, PE, TE):
        self.X = X
        self.Y = Y
        self.VX = VX
        ...
```

This will let you access the attributes of each rocket like so:

```
Saturn_V = Rocket(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9)
Saturn_V.X
>>>1
```

Now instead of nine seperate lists you can use one list of rockets:

```
rocket_list = [Saturn_V, Sputnik, Atlas-Agena ...]
```

An to remove all the information about on specifc rocket you only need to remove one element from the list:

```
del rocket_list[0] #removes Saturn_V and all its attributes
```

Comment: I think you mean `del sublist[i+1:]`

Comment: Lovely, this is exactly what I was looking for! Thanks so much.

Comment: happy to help :)

Comment: Your approach assumes that I'll have many rocket. I basically have 2 tasks do. The first one requires me to produce an orbit of the rocket around a body(I chose Earth). The second task requires me to produce a graph of an orbit as it takes off from Earth to the Moon and then back to Earth again. Can I create an "object" class for Earth, Moon, and rocket with those attributes? Sorry I'm a newbie in Python. I've posted everything on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49960732/simulation-using-runge-kutta-4th-order-method if you want to have a look?

Answer (score 1):

Here's what I was trying to explain in my comment(s). Although I don't know the details of what you're doing, hopefully this will be enough give you the general idea:

```
# Define a class to hold each group of values.
class Example:
    def __init__(x, y, vx, vy, r, t, ke, pe, te):
        self.x  = x
        self.y  = y
        self.vx = vx
        self.vy = vy
        self.r  = r
        self.t  = t
        self.ke = ke
        self.pe = pe
        self.te = te

# Somehow create a list of Example instances.
my_data = [Example(x1, y1, vx1, vy1, r1, t1, ke1, pe1, te1),
           Example(x2, y2, vx2, vy2, r2, t2, ke2, pe2, te2),
             ...
           Example(xN, yN, vxN, vyN, rN, tN, keN, peN, teN)]

# Then you could do what you asked about like this:
for i, elem in enumerate(my_data):
    if elem.ke > elem.pe:  # Done?
        break

del my_data[i+1:]  # Delete remaining elements in my_data.
```

Comment: user3613025: While examining the code in your edit, one thing I noticed that's seems wrong is the placement of `for sublist in [X, Y, VX, VY, R, T, KE, PE, TE]:` loop, which similar to what's in answer you accepted. The problem is it's _inside_ the outer `for i in range (1,N):` loop, which means it gets executed after _every_ iteration of that unless the `break` condition is true. I think it should be at the same level as the `return` so is it only runs once, just before the function returns.

Comment: user3613025: As for adapting your code to do something like what's in my answer, since your using `numpy`, I would suggest making what's name `my_data` in my answer a "[structured array](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.14.0/user/basics.rec.html)" where the fields in it correspond to the values you have (`X`, `Y`, `VX`, etc). Regardless, one way to avoid the need to delete the excess values in the array(s), would be to _not_ pre-allocate them like you're doing. Instead just create each one as needed and `append` it to the resulting list(s)—that way there would be no need to delete anything.